# CSS3 Hover reveal div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, hover

I'm Trying to Achieve this when a div element is hovered over by the user:

[image]

When i hover over the element nothing happens could someone please help me fix this?

here is my markup and SASS:

```css
.birmingham-venue
 background-image: url(/assets/img/birmingham.png)
 background-repeat: no-repeat
 background-size: cover
 padding-bottom: 200px
 padding-left: 0
 padding-right: 0
 margin: 0

 h2 
  margin: 0
  color: #fff
  position: absolute
  bottom: 0
  right: 0
  padding-right: 20px
  padding-bottom: 10px

.leeds-venue
 background-image: url(/assets/img/leeds.png)
 background-repeat: no-repeat
 background-size: cover
 padding-bottom: 200px
 padding-left: 0
 padding-right: 0
 margin: 0

 h2 
  margin: 0
  color: #fff
  position: absolute
  bottom: 0
  right: 0
  padding-right: 20px
  padding-bottom: 10px

.glasgow-venue
 background-image: url(/assets/img/glasgow.png)
 background-repeat: no-repeat
 background-size: cover
 padding-bottom: 200px
 padding-left: 0
 padding-right: 0
 margin: 0

 h2 
  margin: 0
  color: #fff
  position: absolute
  bottom: 0
  right: 0
  padding-right: 20px
  padding-bottom: 10px

.manchester-venue
 background-image: url(/assets/img/manchester.png)
 background-repeat: no-repeat
 background-size: cover
 padding-bottom: 200px
 padding-left: 0
 padding-right: 0
 margin: 0

 h2 
  margin: 0
  color: #fff
  position: absolute
  bottom: 0
  right: 0
  padding-right: 20px
  padding-bottom: 10px

 .hover-content 
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5)
  color: white
  cursor: pointer
  display: table
  height: 150px
  left: 0
  position: absolute
  top: 0
  width: 150px
  opacity: 0

 .hover-content div 
  display: table-cell
  text-align: center
  vertical-align: middle
 &:hover span.text-content
  opacity: 1
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="centers">
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3 no-padding">
       <div class="birmingham-venue">
        <h2>Birmingham</h2>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 no-padding effect4">
       <div class="manchester-venue">
        <h2>Manchester</h2>
     <div class="hover-content">
      <h2>Manchester</h2>
      <p>You gotta roll with it</p>
     </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 no-padding">
       <div class="leeds-venue">
        <h2>Leeds</h2>
       </div>
      </div>
   <div class="col-md-3 no-padding">
       <div class="glasgow-venue">
        <h2>Glasgow</h2>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </section>
```

any help is much appreciated

Thanks 
Tom

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps you.
https://jsfiddle.net/8Ldwm10p/

```
//css FILE
.box {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background: red;
}

.hidden {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: white;
  display:none;
}

.box:hover .hidden {
    display: block;
}

//HTML

<html>


<body>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="hidden">
      Hello there
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

for class  manchester-venue on hover write css manchester-venue:hover{} inside this and similar for rest of classes